# How to loop through cursor?

Tags: sql-server

I dont know why this query returns only the first row infinitely

```
    DECLARE db_cursor1 CURSOR FOR select ilduedt,accountno,ilno from TBPAYSCHED where accountno ='000520285344' and ilno!=0 order by id
    DECLARE @ilduedt datetime;
    DECLARE @accountno varchar(MAX);
    DECLARE @ilno int;
    DECLARE @tempdate datetime;
    OPEN db_cursor1;
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor1 INTO @ilduedt,@accountno,@ilno
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN  
    select @ilduedt,@accountno,@ilno
    END;
    CLOSE db_cursor1;
    DEALLOCATE db_cursor1;
```

tbpaysched

```
accountno    | ilno | ilduedt
------------------------------------------
000520285344    0     2017-07-30 00:00:00.000
000520285344    1     2017-09-15 00:00:00.000
000520285344    2     2017-08-30 00:00:00.000
000520285344    3     2017-09-15 00:00:00.000
```

It only returns the row with ilno 1 infinitely. I dont know but I think I'm missing something stupid.

Comment: The best answer to your question is that you should toss this cursor away and rewrite your process with set based code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed anther `FETCH NEXT` in the while loop, should be :

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
select @ilduedt,@accountno,@ilno
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor1 INTO @ilduedt,@accountno,@ilno    
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not retrieving the next row from the record set with a call to FETCH_NEXT. However, that code above, assuming there is one row in the record set, should result in an infinite loop.

```
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor1 INTO @ilduedt,@accountno,@ilno
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN  
        select @ilduedt,@accountno,@ilno
        FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor1 INTO @ilduedt,@accountno,@ilno
    END;
```